# How to filter a data frame based on another data frame with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have the following data frame:

```
library(tidyverse)
dat <- tribble(
  ~comp_name, ~model, ~status,
  "foo", 0,  "A",
  "foo", 2,  "B", 
  "foo", 3,  "B", 
  "foo", 11, "C", 
  "bar", 0, "X", 
  "bar", 10, "Y",
  "bar", 20, "Z"
)
```

and I have another data frame which I want to use to filter out member in `dat`.

```
wanted_model_dat <- tibble::tribble(
  ~comp_name, ~wanted_model,
  "foo", c(2, 11),
  "bar", c(0, 1),
)
```

Basically, for every `comp_name` in `dat`, I would like to filter (keep) the model where the values is in the corresponding `wanted_model` colum in `wanted_model_dat`.
The final desired result is this:

```
  comp_name model status
  foo           2 B     
  foo          11 C     
  bar           0 X
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

You may try

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  inner_join(unnest(wanted_model_dat , wanted_model), 
             by = c("comp_name", "model" = 'wanted_model'))

  comp_name model status
  <chr>     <dbl> <chr> 
1 foo           2 B     
2 foo          11 C     
3 bar           0 X
```